# Get around tslint: one-variable-per-declaration

Tags: typescript, tslint

How to code under this rule for the following?

```
let someArray = [...];
for (let i = 0, n = someArray.length; i < n; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know that language or tslint, but I imagine the following works: `let i = 0; let n = someArray.length; for (; i<n; i++) { ... }`

Comment: If you don't like that lint rule, just disable it.

Comment: Yeah, this one sounds like a legit reason to disable it. There is no need to create the variable one level up.

Comment: `for (let i = someArray.length; i--; ) { ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is practically a classic in JavaScript.

The tsLint rule is designed to favour readability in your code.

Most people cache the length of the array because they perceive there to be a [performance benefit](https://jsperf.com/for-loop-research). If this is the only reason you are doing it, the potential marginal gain is not worth the readability cost (and it was in fact slower when I ran the JSPerf test in my browser).

So this is the default "tsLint recommended solution"...

```
for (let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
```

In JavaScript, the length property doesn't iterate the array, so the cost is negligible.

If you disagree, you can of course disable the rule - here is the "comment" way to do that.

```
/* tslint:disable:one-variable-per-declaration */
```

Or the config way:

```
"one-variable-per-declaration": false
```

Or in your case, you may want to use the config flag that disables it just for `for` loops:

```
"one-variable-per-declaration": [true, "ignore-for-loop"]
```